# Sending Soap Message into JMS Queue

Tags: java, soap, jms, glassfish-3

I am trying to receive soap message and send that to JMS Queue but it return this error message:

```
Severe: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl cannot be cast to java.io.Serializable
at kics.green.acs.tr069.web.servlet.TR069ACSFrontController.createJMSMessageForjmsACSMessageQueue(TR069ACSFrontController.java:409)
at kics.green.acs.tr069.web.servlet.TR069ACSFrontController.sendJMSMessageToACSMessageQueue(TR069ACSFrontController.java:421)
at kics.green.acs.tr069.web.servlet.TR069ACSFrontController.processRequest(TR069ACSFrontController.java:165)
at kics.green.acs.tr069.web.servlet.TR069ACSFrontController.doPost(TR069ACSFrontController.java:297)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at net.balusc.http.multipart.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:73)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:232)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Severe:     at kics.green.acs.tr069.web.servlet.TR069ACSFrontController.createJMSMessageForjmsACSMessageQueue(TR069ACSFrontController.java:409)
Severe:     at kics.green.acs.tr069.web.servlet.TR069ACSFrontController.sendJMSMessageToACSMessageQueue(TR069ACSFrontController.java:421)
Severe:     at kics.green.acs.tr069.web.servlet.TR069ACSFrontController.processRequest(TR069ACSFrontController.java:165)
Severe:     at kics.green.acs.tr069.web.servlet.TR069ACSFrontController.doPost(TR069ACSFrontController.java:297)
Severe:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
Severe:     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
Severe:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1539)
Severe:     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
Severe:     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
Severe:     at net.balusc.http.multipart.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:73)
Severe:     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
Severe:     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
Severe:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
Severe:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
Severe:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
Severe:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
Severe:     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:98)
Severe:     at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:91)
Severe:     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:162)
Severe:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
Severe:     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
Severe:     at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:232)
Severe:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
Severe:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
Severe:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
Severe:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
Severe:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
Severe:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
Severe:     at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
Severe:     at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
Severe:     at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
Severe:     at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
Severe:     at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
Severe:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
Severe:     at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
Severe:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I am using glassfish 3.1.1.

Here is Code:

```
private Message createJMSMessageForjmsACSMessageQueue(Session session, Object messageData) throws JMSException {
    // TODO create and populate message to send
    ObjectMessage om = session.createObjectMessage();
    om.setObject((Serializable) messageData);
    return om;
}

private void sendJMSMessageToACSMessageQueue(Object messageData) throws JMSException {
    Connection connection = null;
    Session session = null;
    try {
        connection = aCSMessageQueueFactory.createConnection();
        session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        MessageProducer messageProducer = session.createProducer(aCSMessageQueue);
        messageProducer.send(createJMSMessageForjmsACSMessageQueue(session, messageData));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if (session != null) {
            try {
                session.close();
            } catch (JMSException e) {
                Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.WARNING, "Cannot close session", e);
            }
        }
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
    }
```

Error on this line:

```
om.setObject((Serializable) messageData);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem, like the exception says, is that you're trying to cast *com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj.soap.ver1_1.Message1_1Impl* to *java.io.Serializable*, but that class doesn't implement that interface.

You need to pass the SOAP payload in a different way, see https://www.w3.org/TR/soapjms/#binding-message-body